Flask App that generates Word Chronology from Word document
I made this simple Flask App, which takes a paragraph-referenced Word .docx document as an input and downloads a Word .docx document as an output.
I have some worries about security of the design.  The code is creating and deleting files by controlling the OS.  Does this open up a vulnerability?  Could someone put in an executable input and change the behavior of my program?  Or intercept the user-uploaded files and send it off somewhere else?
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import os
from fileinput import filename
import pypandoc 
from datetime import datetime
from flask import *  

app = Flask(__name__)   

def clean_markdown_document(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        content = file.read()

    # Find the position of the first occurrence of "1."
    first_occurrence_index = content.find("1.")
    # Find the position of the first occurrence of a footnote
    first_occurrence_of_footnote = content.find("[^1]:")  

    # Determine the index to cut off the content
    if first_occurrence_index!= -1:
        if first_occurrence_of_footnote!= -1 and first_occurrence_of_footnote > first_occurrence_index:
            cleaned_content = content[:first_occurrence_of_footnote]  # Slice content up to the footnote
        else:
            cleaned_content = content[first_occurrence_index:]  # Keep content from "1." onwards
    else:
        cleaned_content = content  # If "1." is not found, keep the content as is

    with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(cleaned_content)

    print(f"Markdown document cleaned and saved as {output_file}")


def extract_numbered_items_to_csv(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        content = file.read()

    # Regex pattern to find numbered items
    pattern = r'(\d+)\.\s*(.*?)\n(?=\d+\.\s|$)'  # Matches numbers followed by text, ending with a new line before another number

    # Find all matches
    matches = re.findall(pattern, content, re.DOTALL)

    # Write the matches to a CSV file
    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(['Number', 'Text'])  # Writing header

        for number, text in matches:
            writer.writerow([number, text.strip()])  # Writing each row with number and text

    print(f"Data has been extracted and saved to {output_file}")


def parse_date(date_str):
    # Attempt to parse the date string into a datetime object
    date_formats = [
        '%m/%d/%Y', '%m-%d-%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%m-%d-%y',
        '%d %B %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%B %d, %Y', '%b %d, %Y',
        '%Y-%m-%d'
    ]
    
    for date_format in date_formats:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(date_str, date_format)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    
    return None

def extract_dates(input_file, output_file):
    extracted_data = []

    # Define regular expression patterns for common date formats
    date_patterns = [
        r'\b(\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2,4})\b',  # MM/DD/YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY or MM/DD/YY or MM-DD-YY
        r'\b(\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3,9} \d{2,4})\b',  # DD Month YYYY
        r'\b([A-Za-z]{3,9} \d{1,2}, \d{2,4})\b',  # Month DD, YYYY
        r'\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\b'  # YYYY-MM-DD
    ]

    with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        
        for row in reader:
            paragraph_number = row['Number']  # Get the paragraph number
            text = row['Text']  # Get the text
            
            for pattern in date_patterns:
                matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
                for match in matches:
                    try:
                        # Attempt to parse the match into a datetime object
                        date = parse_date(match)
                        if date:
                            extracted_data.append({'Date': date, 'Text': text, 'Paragraph Number': paragraph_number})
                    except ValueError:
                        # Ignore if the match cannot be parsed into a valid date
                        pass

    extracted_data.sort(key=lambda x: x['Date'])

    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Date', 'Text', 'Paragraph Number']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        
        writer.writeheader()
        
        for entry in extracted_data:
            writer.writerow({'Date': entry['Date'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), 
                             'Text': entry['Text'], 
                             'Paragraph Number': entry['Paragraph Number']})

    print(f"Date extraction completed and saved to {output_file}")

def create_word_document_from_csv(input_file, output_file):
    data = pd.read_csv(input_file)

    # Create a new Word document
    doc = Document()

    # Add a title to the document (optional)
    doc.add_heading('Draft Chronology', level=1)

    table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
    table.style = 'Table Grid'  # Optional: set a table style

    # Add the header row
    hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    hdr_cells[0].text = 'Date'
    hdr_cells[1].text = 'Text'
    hdr_cells[2].text = 'Paragraph Number'

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells  # Add a new row
        row_cells[0].text = str(row['Date'])  # Fill Date
        row_cells[1].text = str(row['Text'])  # Fill Text
        row_cells[2].text = str(row['Paragraph Number'])  # Fill Paragraph Number

    doc.save(output_file)

    print(f"Word document '{output_file}' created successfully.")


def everything_function(f):
    try:
        pypandoc.convert_file(f, 'md', outputfile='input.md')
        clean_markdown_document('input.md', 'cleaned.md')
        extract_numbered_items_to_csv('cleaned.md', 'all_dates.csv')
        extract_dates('all_dates.csv', 'dates_extracted.csv')
        create_word_document_from_csv('dates_extracted.csv', 'draft-chronology.docx')

    finally:
        # Remove intermediate files
        for file in [f, 'input.md', 'cleaned.md', 'all_dates.csv', 'dates_extracted.csv']:
            if os.path.exists(file):
                os.remove(file)
                print(f"Removed {file}")


@app.route('/')   
def main():
    everything_function() 

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app.run(debug=True)

I would like to share the link to the App with my friends, but do not want to expose anyone to unnecessary risks.  Despite my express warnings, some people may put in a Word .docx file with some confidential information on it.
For more background see this write-up: I am aware the approach taken is very circuitous (even absurd), but performance / maintainability would not be an issue at this stage, given that very few people would use it.

Path
You currently have the following signatures:
def clean_markdown_document(input_file: str, output_file: str) -> None:
    ...
def extract_numbered_items_to_csv(input_file: str, output_file: str) -> None:
    ...
def extract_dates(input_file: str, output_file: str) -> None:
    ...
def create_word_document_from_csv(input_file: str, output_file: str) -> None:

It would be more convenient to accept Path args, rather than str.
DRY
Repetition such as this is regrettable:
        clean_markdown_document('input.md', 'cleaned.md')
        extract_numbered_items_to_csv(..., 'all_dates.csv')
        extract_dates(..., 'dates_extracted.csv')
        ...
        # Remove intermediate files
        for file in [f, 'input.md', 'cleaned.md', 'all_dates.csv', 'dates_extracted.csv']:

We have a very clear data pipeline happening here.
It would be more convenient for each function to
return the Path of its output file.
We could use that to accumulate a list of intermediate
files which need to be removed.
(I am very sympathetic to the diagnostic value
of persisting the output file results during debugging,
so you can tell what works and what needs to be improved.)
Consider creating this list of functions:
    steps = [
        clean_markdown_document,
        extract_numbered_items_to_csv,
        extract_dates,
        create_word_document_from_csv,
    ]

Then for step in steps: could rip through the pipeline,
either deleting temp files as it goes or accumulating them
for a final deletion.
Kudos on breaking out small, well-defined steps.
attrgetter
This is a nice enough anonymous function:
    extracted_data.sort(key=lambda x: x["Date"])

But the usual name we give that would be
attrgetter("Date").
repeated I/O
I don't have a problem with each stage reading
what the previous stage wrote to the filesystem,
as it isn't a bottleneck.
But you might consider passing around StringIO buffers,
or strings, or lists of dicts, or Pandas dataframes.
For one thing, that will likely make it easier to write automated
unit tests
of your business logic.
